# How to fill matrix with random numbers in R?

Tags: r, matrix

```
expand.grid(i=rexp(5,rate=0.1))
```

It creates just one col but is there some way to multiply this easily to 5 cols? I mean the matlab-way-of-doing-things like `rand('exp', 0.1, 10,20)` (creating a matrix with exponentially-distributed-random-numbers with mean 0.1 of size 10x20), how?

Comment: ...why downvotes on this? I like simple stupid questions, one can learn surprising a lot from them idiomatically -- look how many are using slightly different styles, interesting.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the mouse-over text includes the phrase "does not show any research effort". So I'm guessing someone may have thought that even the most basic research would have turned up the answer to this question. (And IMHO, there is no meaningful difference in the current answers. I was considering deleting mine to reduce clutter.)

Comment: I agree -- hard to see how someone found `expand.grid` before finding `matrix` and, say, `rnorm` .  Perhaps the OP could have helped by saying something like "I can't find documentation on creating a matrix" to show where the real problem lies.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the [matrix](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html) function:

```
matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
```

ETA: If you want to do it without repeating the 200, you can define a function to do so:

```
fill.matrix = function(expr, nrow=1, ncol=1) {
    matrix(eval(expr, envir=list(x=nrow*ncol)), nrow=nrow, ncol=ncol)
}

fill.matrix(rexp(x, rate=.1), nrow=10, ncol=20)
```

The `x` thus becomes the dummy variable you're talking about. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: any idea whether there is some filler-flag for 200? I mean to create the matrix like this `matrix(rexp(___, rate=10), ncol=20, nrow=10)`? During fast prototyping, I tend to forget just the 200 things --- making clutter/newbie -style mistakes.

Comment: It is close +1 for good Try! Sorry about being perfectionist but I am thinking another way. There must be somehow still to keep the structure...

Comment: Do you mean "there must be some way that Matlab syntax works *exactly* the same in R"? There isn't.

Comment: Sorry but `matrix(rexp(matrix(nrow=2, ncol=3), rate=.1), nrow=2, ncol=3)` keeps the structure so at least one poor-looking way works -- now some way to `reuse` the logic? Look one needs to reuse the logic in two locations outside/inside and just operate it two times -- any ready-built function for this repetition or some XYZapply-hack?

Comment: `> rexp(matrix(nrow=2, ncol=3), rate=.1)
[1] 11.806251  8.144781  2.776993  4.010121  2.150048  4.230967
> matrix(rexp(matrix(nrow=2, ncol=3), rate=.1), nrow=2, ncol=3)
           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 22.7861890 11.98009 5.771602
[2,]  0.7222509 86.88183 6.027278` -- one gives matrix-looking -output while the other as a list-looking output, matrix-looking output is visually-more-pleasing but it is code-clutter due to repetition.

Comment: Yes, it works now as the intention -- but I find it still odd that no other way to do this (feels a bit hxckish way to create a function like that, not possible with defaults?!). Perhaps, this is the simplest way or perhaps there is some functional way to do this, I don't know. Well, have to research myself this answer and around this question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it's what you're looking for, hhh. But with all respect, your problem is no longer with the language but with the idea that a language could possibly be missing a feature built-in to another language. Often that's simply the case.

Answer (score 15):

you can do something like:

```
matrix(rexp(200), 10)
```

And of course use what ever distribution you want.

Comment: ..yes this is handy, used it one time but forgot it immediately -- for some reason, I find it easier to remember the M -style-method because it is much more explicit -- this contains a ton of thing implicitly (and you need to make sure the counts match).

Answer (score 10):

`?matrix` will tell you lots! and `rexp` is the function to generate a random exponential distribution.

```
mat <- matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 10, ncol = 20)
```

Comment: ...there is something I have never understood here, the term `rate` -- why it is not 0.1 as mean? Ok, `-- with rate ‘rate’
     (i.e., mean ‘1/rate’).`, this is a part in the manual never understood: does it mean $\mu=\frac{1}{rate}$? Yes, it tells a lot but in an obscure way. Now back to this answer -- is there some way to implicitly rm the 200? It is obvious in the intention of the M -style way of doing things. I mean like this `Matrix(mean=0.1, dims=c(20,30), type=c('random', 'exp'))`?

Comment: Regarding the parameter of the distribution, I believe it's just nomenclature. R have to choose one! Lots of distributions have more than one nomenclature to its parameters.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
matris=matrix(rnorm(10),5,20)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a uniformly distributed 10 by 15 random matrix in the following code line:

```
matrix(runif(10*15), nrow = 10, ncol = 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
replicate(rexp(10),20)
```